# how to assign an Event to an element that may change based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Background:** I am using a snippet of JQuery to assign an event to an element based on its ID. That event slides a menu from the left side of the screen.

**Question:** When the screen size changes to < 710px I am going to hide the original element and show a new element (which is just a different icon). But I want that new element to trigger the same event.

Should I just assign the event to both elements one after another or can I combine that into one Event?

Below is an example of my HTML JS and CSS 
**PLEASE NOTE THE TRIGGER WILL NOT WORK UNLESS THE TEST WINDOW IS ABOVE 711PX**

```js
 window.onload = function(){

   document.getElementById('megga-nav-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
       var documentBody = $('#megga-global-menu');
       documentBody.toggleClass('is-active');
       if (documentBody.hasClass('hide-megga')) {
           documentBody.removeClass('hide-megga');
          
           return;
       }
       documentBody.addClass('hide-megga');
       
   });

   document.getElementById("megga-global-menu").addEventListener("mouseleave", menuHide);


  };
   function menuHide() {
       document.getElementById("megga-global-menu").classList.add('hide-megga');
   }
```

```css
   #megga-global-menu {
       background: red ;
       position: fixed;
       top: 50px;
       bottom: 0;
       left:0px;
       width: 200px;
       z-index: 1000000;
       transition: ease all .6s;
   }
   #megga-global-menu.hide-megga {
       left: -200px;
       transition: ease all .6s;
   }
    #megga-nav-toggle {
       display: inline-block;
       z-index:999998;
       font-size: 30px;
       color: #000;
       cursor: pointer;
   }

@media screen and (min-width: 710px) {
    #megga-navmobile-toggle {
        display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 710px) {
    #megga-nav-toggle {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="megga-nav-toggle">FULL SCREEN</span><Bn/><Br/>

<span id="megga-navmobile-toggle">MOBILE SCREEN</span>




<div id="megga-global-menu" class="">
My slide out menu goes here!
</div>
```

Comment: `Should I just assign the event to both elements one after another or can I combine that into one Event?` i would say yes ... and to avoid repeating your self make the logic inside a function

Comment: Thanks for the advice @TemaniAfif if that is the most efficient way to accomplish my request that is the route I will go.

Comment: well, this my advice ... i cannot confirm it's the most efficient way :) maybe you will get better advices ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but if you want just show different icon based on screen size, why not put both of them in the same element and display the wanted icon with @media?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 710px) {
  #megga-navmobile-toggle-icon { display: none; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 710px) {
  #megga-nav-toggle-icon { display: none; }
}
```

And your html should be:

```
<div id="megga-nav-toggle">
  <span id="megga-nav-toggle-icon">FULL SCREEN</span><Bn/><Br/>
  <span id="megga-navmobile-toggle-icon">MOBILE SCREEN</span>
</div>
```